# How to make bootRepackage depends on jar not war when using Gradle War Plugin

Tags: gradle, jar, spring-boot, war

Without Gradle War Plugin, `bootRepackage` task depends on `jar` task but with Gradle War Plugin, it depends on `war` task.

How can I change it to depend on `jar` task even though I'm using Gradle War Plugin?

UPDATE:

I'm using `war` task to create a war file including documents to be deployed to a documentation server and I want to use `bootRepackage`d jar file to provide a service. My `war` task depends on `asciidoctor` task which depends on `test` task (I'm using Spring REST Docs.) but I don't want to run `asciidoctor` task or `test` task when using `bootRepackage` task.

I solved my problem with the following setup:

```
ext {
    mainClassName = 'com.izeye.throwaway.Application'
}

task myBootRepackage(type: BootRepackage, dependsOn: jar) {
}
```

but I'm not sure this is a good practice.

This is a sample project having the above configuration:

https://github.com/izeye/spring-boot-throwaway-branches/tree/war

Comment: I'm not really sure, what you want to achieve by this, but may be you shlould try to create some custom task of type Jar(or may be pass only `jar`) and configure the plugin as `bootRepackage {
    withJarTask = customJarTask
}` due to this reference http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-gradle-repackage-configuration

Comment: @Stanislav Thanks for the comment. I updated my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should have been able to do this:

```
bootRepackage {
    withJarTask jar
}
```

While this correctly causes the jar task's jar to be repackaged, it doesn't remove the dependency on the war task. This is another symptom of [this Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3931).

Until this issue has been resolved, the approach that you've taken – declaring your own BootRepackage task and manually configuring the tasks that it depends upon – is your best option.